# insufficient privileges to complete the operation - service principal

Tags: azure

I have created an Service Principal and when I tried to run "az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth > test.azureauth" y received the following error:

"insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

I gave the following permissions:

**Microsoft Graph:**

Application.ReadWrite.All

Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy

Directory.Read.All

Directory.ReadWrite.All

User.Read

But with this permissions is still failing

Any ideas?

Comment: `Application.ReadWrite.All` - this should be enough. you sure you gave it permissions and did logout\login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign Permission to `Azure Active Directory Graph` then it will work well.

[image]

Also, you could assign `Global administrator` role to your service principal.

**Note : This will take several minutes to take effect**.

[image]

Comment: any other idea? Because the SP has this 4 permissions but Im receiving "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Comment: It is `Azure Active Directory Graph` instead `microsoft graph`.

Comment: sorry! I changed to Azure Active Directory Graph but now im receiving this error:creating a role assignment under the scope of "XX"
  Role assignment creation failed.

The client 'XX' with object id 'XX' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/XX' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Comment: Go to your `Subscription` > `Access control`> `Add role assignment`, add **Owner** role to your service principal like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJrqX.png).